# Theme stops media uploader from working

Tags: themes, uploads, post-thumbnails, media

I took over a website from a previous developer that built most of the site. Because the theme was a custom one, he chose to do it using [Toolbox](http://theme.wordpress.com/retired/toolbox/). The site has been standing for just over a year, and was given to me so we can finish it.

I have an issue where I can't upload an image to a post using [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) and this theme. I've determined that it's not ACF, as I've changed the theme to the default Twenty Fourteen theme that you get with Wordpress, and then image uploading works fine to that post.

After some research, I realised that the theme did not have theme support for thumbnails, so I added it by placing `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');` to my `toolbox_setup` method in my `functions.php` file. Currently that method looks like this:

```
function toolbox_setup() {
    /**
     * Make theme available for translation
     * Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory
     * If you're building a theme based on toolbox, use a find and replace
     * to change 'toolbox' to the name of your theme in all the template files
     */
    load_theme_textdomain( 'toolbox', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

    $locale = get_locale();
    $locale_file = get_template_directory() . "/languages/$locale.php";
    if ( is_readable( $locale_file ) )
        require_once( $locale_file );

    /**
     * Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head
     */
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

    /**
     * This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
     */
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'toolbox' ),
    ) );

    /**
     * Add support for the Aside and Gallery Post Formats
     */
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'image', 'gallery' ) );

    // Enable support for Post Thumbnails, and declare two sizes.
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 672, 372, true );
    add_image_size( 'toolbox-full-width', 1038, 576, true );
}
```

As I am pretty new to WordPress, I have no idea if simply doing this will solve the issue. Do I need to reload the theme? Do I have to add this somewhere else? How do I fix this issue?

**UPDATE 1**

I turned on debugging and this is the errors I get. This is only when I open the media uploader. I've noticed that it does actually upload the files, it just doesn't show / load them.

```
[06-Oct-2014 06:55:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/me/Server/intune/wp-content/themes/toolbox/functions.php on line 303
[06-Oct-2014 06:55:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/me/Server/intune/wp-content/themes/toolbox/functions.php on line 305
[06-Oct-2014 06:55:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/me/Server/intune/wp-content/themes/toolbox/functions.php on line 303
[06-Oct-2014 06:55:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/me/Server/intune/wp-content/themes/toolbox/functions.php on line 305
```

This are the corresponding lines in the code:

```
/**
 * Filter in a link to a content ID attribute for the next/previous image links on image attachment pages
 */
function toolbox_enhanced_image_navigation( $url ) { //300
    global $post, $wp_rewrite; //301

    $id = (int) $post->ID; //303
    $object = get_post( $id ); //304
    if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $post->ID ) && ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() && ( $object->post_parent > 0 ) && ( $object->post_parent != $id ) ) ) //305
        $url = $url . '#main'; //306

    return $url; //308
}
add_filter( 'attachment_link', 'toolbox_enhanced_image_navigation' ); //310
```

Comment: but re-reading this... 
Toolbox I've never used, but I think you should be able to move the add_theme set_post and the rest to outside of the toolbox_setup function

Comment: Adding thumbnail support won't fix your problem with image uploading. You need to determine what is in this custom theme that is causing the problem, and fix it or remove it.

Comment: can you upload images as part of the content?

Comment: @Otto, any suggestions on how I could do this? I've updated my answer with some errors I received, perhaps that helps.

Comment: Does image uploads work if you remove the function that is returning those errors

Comment: Hi @PieterGoosen, I've answered the question before I saw your comment. The image uploader works now, and I haven't seen any implications.

Comment: Great to hear it is working now. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by just removing the function that threw the error. I have not seen any implications yet. Image upload is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to reload anything you will need to hook this fucntion into a hook so it's actually run something like this should do it:

```
do_action( 'init', 'toolbox_setup' );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action

Comment: I think is add_action( 'init', 'toolbox_setup' );

Comment: Doesn't work. Right after the function I have `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'toolbox_setup' );`. I've added your suggestion, however still no luck.